# Primefaces datatable - Edit & Delete buttons no longer working after adding filter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, datatable

I had a datatable built with primefaces 5.1 that was working perfectly until I added the filtering options. I've been through the forum and I've tried the suggestions but none of them have worked for me so far. This was the [closest suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27923993/primefaces-loses-data-in-dialog-after-filter-the-datatable) that I could find:

Each row of my datatable has an edit and remove button. Before I add the search filter code, I can click on edit and a pre-populated form will show up with the correct details, also delete works. Once I add the filtering code to the primefaces datatable, I get a blank form once I click on edit. The delete button also ceases working.

The datatable:

```
    <p:growl id="messages" />
    <h2>Company</h2>

    <h:form id="form1">
        <p:dataTable value="#{companyController.companies}" var="company" id="companyTable" widgetVar="filteredcompanyTable"
                 emptyMessage="No records found with given criteria" filteredValue="#{companyController.filteredCompanies}">

            <p:column headerText="Name" sortBy="#{company.company_name}" filterBy="#{company.company_name}" filterMatchMode="contains">
                #{company.company_name}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Description">
                    #{company.company_description}
            </p:column>     
            <p:column headerText="Enabled">
                #{companyController.checkEnabled(company.enabled)}
            </p:column> 
            <p:column headerText="Updated" sortBy="#{company.date_modified}">
                #{companyController.formatDate(company.date_modified)}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Registered" sortBy="#{company.date_registered}">
                #{companyController.formatDate(company.date_registered)}
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Options">
                <h:form>
                    <p:commandButton value="edit" action="#{companyController.setCompany(company)}" update=":form1:companyForm" 
                        oncomplete="PF('companyDialog').show(); " resetValues="true" />
                    <p:commandButton value="remove" action="#{companyController.remove(company)}" update=":form1:companyTable, :messages">
                        <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="Are you sure?" icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </h:form>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>

        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton value="add company" action="#{companyController.clear()}" update=":form1:companyForm" 
                oncomplete="PF('companyDialog').show()" resetValues="true" />
        </h:form>

        <p:dialog widgetVar="companyDialog" closeOnEscape="true" modal="true" header="company">
            <h:form id="companyForm">
                <p:focus />
                <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                    name:
                    <p:inputText value="#{companyController.company.company_name}" />
                    description:
                    <p:inputText value="#{companyController.company.company_description}" />
                    enabled:
                    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{companyController.company.enabled}" />

                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{companyController.save()}" update="companyForm, :form1:companyTable, :messages"
                    oncomplete="handleDialogSubmit(args, 'companyDialog'); PF('filteredcompanyTable').filter();" />
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>

    <h:form>
        <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" closeOnEscape="true">
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
            <p:commandButton value="No" type="button" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </p:confirmDialog>
    </h:form>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleDialogSubmit(args, dialogName) {
            if(!args.validationFailed) {
                PF(dialogName).hide();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Below is the code for the underlying view:

```
public class CompanyController implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManagedProperty("#{companyService}")
    private CompanyService companyService;

    private List<Company> companies;
    private List<Company> filteredCompanies;
    private Company company = new Company();

    @PostConstruct
    public void loadCompanies() {
        companies = companyService.fetchAll();
    }

    public void save() {
        companyService.save(company);
        clear();
        loadCompanies();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Company saved!", null));
    }

    public void remove(Company company) {
        companyService.delete(company);
        loadCompanies();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Company de-registered!", null));
    }

    public void clear() {
        company = new Company();
    }

    public String formatDate(Date date) {
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        return formatter.format(date);
    }

    public String checkEnabled(boolean status) {
        if (status==true) {return "YES";}
        return "NO";
    }

}
```

Kindly assist

Comment: No matter if the nested forms were there all the time you have to fix it.. And probably better to move the dialog outside of any other form ( = bottom of page)

Comment: Nested forms don't work

Comment: Hi guys. The above problem was caused by nesting UIForms, thanks for the help. God bless

Comment: Jaqen H'ghar - thanks, it's fixed noq